# Conditionally concatenate string over multiple rows

Tags: r, string, string-concatenation

I have extracted multiple tables from a PDF which contains strings over multiple lines. I have used the extract_table() function from the tabulizer package, the only problem being that the strings import as separate rows.

e.g.

```
action <- c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA)

description <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b")

data.frame(action, description)

       action description
1       1           a
2      NA           b
3      NA           c
4       2           a
5      NA           b
6       3           a
7      NA           b
8      NA           c
9      NA           d
10      4           a
11     NA           b
```

I would like to concatenate the strings so that they appear as the same element such as:

```
  action description
1      1       a b c
2      2         a b
3      3     a b c d
4      4         a b
```

Hope that makes sense, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tidyverse` way would be to `fill` the `action` column with previous non-NA value then `group_by` `Action` and `paste` the `description` together.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 fill(action) %>%
 group_by(action) %>%
 summarise(description = paste(description, collapse = " "))


#  action description
#   <dbl> <chr>      
#1     1. a b c      
#2     2. a b        
#3     3. a b c d    
#4     4. a b
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option

```
dat <- data.frame(action, description)
aggregate(
  description ~ action,
  transform(dat, action = cumsum(!is.na(dat$action))),
  FUN = paste,
  ... = collapse = " "
)
#  action description
#1      1       a b c
#2      2         a b
#3      3     a b c d
#4      4         a b
```

For `aggregate` to work we need to change `action` to what is returned by `cumsum(!is.na(dat$action)))`, i.e.

```
cumsum(!is.na(dat$action)))
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(description = paste(description, collapse = ' ')), 
                  .(action = cumsum(!is.na(action)))]
#   action description
#1:      1       a b c
#2:      2         a b
#3:      3     a b c d
#4:      4         a b
```

---

Or using `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
setDT(df1)[, .(description = paste(description, collapse = ' ')),
              .(action = na.locf(action))]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(action, description)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `zoo` and `dplyr` packages like so

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
action <- c(1, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA)
description <- c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b")
df = data.frame(action, description)
df$action = na.locf(df$action)
df = 
    df %>% 
    group_by(action) %>% 
    summarise(description = paste(description, collapse = ' '))
```